# Create API in Vaadin project

Tags: java, api, vaadin

I have a Vaadin Project that I didn't wrote. I didn't do anything with Vaadin before. Now I have to implement an API and Web Services for further communication.

So my question is: Is it possible to create web services and a further URL structure to the project besides the Vaadin stuff?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin is just a User Interface framework - for the presentation layer.You can write your service layer separately from the presentation layer as usual. So you can use whatever framework or mechanism you are familliar with in java or better yet just add more web services in a same way the old ones are published to preserve consistency.

Comment: Just make sure to route "your" webservice URL's to the correct classes, Vaadin per default catches all sub-url's